# Why is this custom Angular filter not returning any expected matches?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of "event" objects that contain a "startDate" property. I've written a custom filter, "occursToday", that is expected to return an array of events that have a startDate property matching the "today" variable as defined in the filter function. The code below is my attempt to test my custom filter. No events are displayed, yet there are expected matches. No errors are thrown in the console either. What am I missing or misunderstanding? Thank you.

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.filter('occursToday', function () {
  return function (events) {
    var today = new Date('12/1/2014');
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var evnt = events[i];
      if (evnt.startDate === today) {
        filtered.push(evnt);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});


myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello world!';
    $scope.events = [
      {"name": "An Event", "venue": "A Park", "startDate": new Date('12/1/2014'), "startTime": new Date('12/1/2014'), "endDate": new Date('12/1/2014'), "endTime": new Date('12/1/2014'), "website": "www.example.org", "description":"Yada yada.", "details": "Blah blah."},
      {"name": "An Event", "venue": "A Park", "startDate": new Date('12/1/2014'), "startTime": new Date('12/1/2014'), "endDate": new Date('12/1/2014'), "endTime": new Date('12/1/2014'), "website": "www.example.org", "description":"Yada yada.", "details": "Blah blah."},
      {"name": "An Event", "venue": "A Park", "startDate": new Date('12/2/2014'), "startTime": new Date('12/2/2014'), "endDate": new Date('12/2/2014'), "endTime": new Date('12/2/2014'), "website": "www.example.org", "description":"Yada yada.", "details": "Blah blah."},
      {"name": "An Event", "venue": "A Park", "startDate": new Date('12/2/2014'), "startTime": new Date('12/2/2014'), "endDate": new Date('12/2/2014'), "endTime": new Date('12/2/2014'), "website": "www.example.org", "description":"Yada yada.", "details": "Blah blah."},
      {"name": "An Event", "venue": "A Park", "startDate": new Date('12/3/2014'), "startTime": new Date('12/3/2014'), "endDate": new Date('12/3/2014'), "endTime": new Date('12/3/2014'), "website": "www.example.org", "description":"Yada yada.", "details": "Blah blah."},
    ]
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>myApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

      <div class="upcoming_events">
        <h2>Today</h2>
          <ul class="event_list">

            <li ng-repeat="event in events | occursToday">
              <div class="event">
                <div class="event_date">
                  <span class="day_of_week">{{event.startDate | date: 'EEEE'}}</span><br>
                  {{event.startDate | date: 'mediumDate'}}
                </div>
                <div class="event_content">
                  <a class="summary" href="#">{{event.name}}</a>
                  <time class="start-time">{{event.startTime | date: 'shortTime'}}</time>
                  –
                  <time class="end-time">{{event.endTime | date: 'shortTime'}}</time>
                  <a class="location" href="#">{{event.venue}}</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use

```
       evnt.startDate.getTime() === today.getTime()
```

Comment: The above is the correct answer for the code I provided. However, for the benefit of anyone uses this as reference, I'd like to clarify that the above will only return true if the two Date objects are instantiated on the exact point in time. For a more general filter that will match Date objects of the same date, regardless of the time of day, the condition used will have to be  `if (evnt.startDate.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() &&
          evnt.startDate.getMonth() === today.getMonth() &&
          evnt.startDate.getDate() === today.getDate())`

Comment: Actually that's not quite right. If you instantiate a date as new Date('12/25/2015') then it will initialize to Fri Dec 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) no matter what time of day you create it. The hh:mm:ss are not included by default when instantiated in that way.

Comment: Yes, that's right. What I mean, is that in the final version of the above code the `today` variable will initialize simply as `today = new Date()` so that it matches the given day automatically, but `new Date()` instantiates a time down to the current millisecond, whereas and `evnt.startDate` will be initated with the zeroed time format you describe above. So I do need to use that more lengthy condition to match only the dates.